# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm struggling with this line in the **_form**: `<%= simple_form_for(@post, url: blog_path) do |f| %>`, which gives me the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Keep in mind that in my **routes** I have: `resources :blog, controller: 'posts'`, which is to say I am working off of a posts MVC, but I wanted /posts/ to be replaced by /blog/ in the routes.

**posts_controller**

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
  end
```

The _form works when I go to `edit`, but not create `new`.

**routes**

```
           blog_index GET    /blog(.:format)                                                     posts#index
                      POST   /blog(.:format)                                                     posts#create
             new_blog GET    /blog/new(.:format)                                                 posts#new
            edit_blog GET    /blog/:id/edit(.:format)                                            posts#edit
                 blog GET    /blog/:id(.:format)                                                 posts#show
                      PATCH  /blog/:id(.:format)                                                 posts#update
                      PUT    /blog/:id(.:format)                                                 posts#update
                      DELETE /blog/:id(.:format)                                                 posts#destroy
```

Comment: Why do you submit post to a blog controller?

Comment: Same error @KMRakibulIslam :(

Comment: @BroiSatse I'm not submitting to a blog controller. I'm submitting to a posts_controller. There is no blog controller, model, views, etc. It is all posts. I just use "blog" for the routes instead

Comment: Same error @KMRakibulIslam. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com by specifying `url: blog_path`, you're pointing the form to `posts#show`, which you should never do. Assuming you want to hit your `create` action, you should use `blogs_path`. Not sure if the default for `simple_form` is `:post`, so if it's not, add `method: :post`.

Comment: Sorry how would that look @mmichael. Can you provide the answer below. I've tried: `<%= simple_form_for(:post, url: blogs_path) do |f| %>` and that gives `undefined local variable or method 'blogs_path'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got best of both worlds this way:

```
resources :blog, to: 'posts'
resources :posts
```

Answer (score 2):

`model_path` by default routing logic in Rails leads to `blog#show` => `/blogs/:id`

Change it to `blogs_path`.

Looking at you routes, I see obvious naming conflict, you must be defined routes wrong.

Be sure it looks like `resources :posts, :as=>"blogs"`, both plural.

**UPD**
If you want to have only one blog, then `resource :post, :as=>"blog"`, both singular.

But that means one actual input. I'm quite sure you speak of `blog/post1`, `blog/post2`, otherwise I can't see any sense in calling it blog?

Comment: I get `undefined local variable or method 'blogs_path'`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, provide `rake routes ` output

Comment: Good call. Updated question

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, do you resources look like I updated? Both plural?

Comment: Yes, that's the key, making sure the plurality of `resources` matches that of `:blogs`.

Comment: I don't want to change it to plural though because wouldnt it make the route become www.livetochallenge.com/blogs, which wouldnt make sense because it is a singular blog www.livetochallenge.com/blog. Is there no work around?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, you said that 'blog' actually related to 'post'. Do you want to have only one post available? May be you mean one blog which has many posts?

Comment: For example I want www.livetochallenge.com/blog to work from posts#index. I want www.livetochallenge.com/blog/new to use posts#new. With my version everything works except the new action. With the suggestions you made it would be www.livetochallenge/blogs or livetochallenge/posts, which is not what Im going for here. Sorry if im not explaining myself well.

Comment: resources :blog, to: 'posts' is another way to write what I wrote, but still runs into the error presented

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, you either go plural and blogs_path, either singular and blog path, if it doesn't work your mistake is not matching route declaration to path

Answer (score 2):

sorry my english...

`<%= simple_form_for(@post, url: blog_path) do |f| %>` In this line you are redirecting the form to show (blog_path) 
But , depending on the route , the show needs an id **(blog GET    /blog/:id(.:format))**.

You must create a "create" method in the controller that receives the parameters strong ...

There is another method you can use: rails generate scaffold_controller posts

This will build the full CRUD , so you only have to configure the parameters

I hope that helps you